# How to fix infinite scroll logic after changing components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-router

I have a component that displays list of recipes in my firestore database, I am using react-infinite-scroll component package.
Everything works, however once I click on one of the items it takes me to another component and when I go back with react router, useEffect starts calling for items on scroll again, even though all data is displayed already.

How Can I build a logic that once I return to the component it remembers where I left off?

```
const [mealSearchResults, setMealSearchResults] = useContext(
    mealSearchResultsContext
  );
  const [latestMealDoc, setLatestMealDoc] = useContext(latestMealDocContext);
  const getNextMeals = async () => {
    const ref = db
      .collection("meals")
      .orderBy("timestamp")
      .limit(6)
      .startAfter(latestMealDoc || 0);
    const data = await ref.get();
    data.docs.forEach((doc) => {
      const meal = doc.data();
      setMealSearchResults((prev: any) => [...prev, meal]);
    });
setLatestMealDoc((prev: any) => data.docs[data.docs.length - 1]);
 };
 useEffect(() => {
    getNextMeals();
  }, []);
```

Comment: I want to fully understand, the issue is with the paging? or that when you navigate on the app back to the list the scrolling function is called again?

Comment: @SoniSol the issue is that it starts fetching the items again, and ignores the latest doc reference, check this video this is what is happening. [effect example](https://i.imgur.com/800weNM.mp4)